# error installing apache Cordova tools in visual studio 2013

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, websocket4net

i want to use Apache Cordova in visual studio 2013.
I followed the instructions on installing Apache tools manually from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx)

When i create new project with Template apache cordova app get this error:
[image: error apache]

1-Android  package

I installed latest the Android SDK with the following package:
[image: package android]

2-WebSocket4Net
I Downloaded WebSocket4Net(0.9).Binaries.zip from [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=403031)
and installed visual studio in drive D :
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ToolWindows

then copied WebSocket4Net.dll to ToolWindows folder

Answer (score 1):

Seems you alreay have the required component installed.

It might be a false alarm by the visual studio dependency checker. Actually, I have some warnings as well, but everything works well. If you did not encounter any problem during building app, feel free to ignore the warning. WebSocket4Net is only required for win7 and if ripple works well, leave it there.

P.S. don't upgrade Android 24.3.2 for now, because there is a known issue that will cause build fail when trying deploy on Android device and android emulator.